# Chess engine speed in python

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, chess

Hi!

I've written a chess engine in python. For search i'm using a minimax algorithm with alpha beta pruning. My evaluation function is very basic, it just assignes a score to the board based on the piece values still on the board. For board representation i use a mailbox approach, 0x88 board representation in particular.

The problem is though, that my search is very very slow. I haven't implemented any kind of move ordering algorithm yet, but still, it takes over two minutes (sometimes even twice as much) to search with a ply of 4. The average number of moves per position is about 23 and to search 4 ply at the starting position, it only looks at about 20 000 nodes.

20 000 nodes in 2-4 minutes seems very slow to me. My question is that , is python just too slow for a chess engine, or might there be something wrong with my implementation?

Comment: Profile your implementation to see what's taking so long (http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html), and come back with a specific code snippet or algorithm demonstrating your bottleneck. Just asking  'is Python just too slow for a chess engine?' is i) not precise enough / too broad to be objectively answered and ii) argumentative.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you won't need to create another question - once you've provided enough information, this question will soon be reopened (if it's to be closed now).